# How can I let Windows XP read Mac OS Extended (Journaled) drives?

Tags: hard-drive, disk-format, windows

How can I let another PC using Windows XP (Service Pack3) read Mac OS Extended (Journaled) volumes? Windows XP shows nothing.

Comment: Where is XP in relation to OS X?  Are they on the same machine using Bootcamp or over a network?

Comment: @traisjames No, another PC.

Comment: Ok so your connecting over the network correct?  Just need to know which way to answer...I do both of these all the time.

Answer (score 3):

### Boot Camp Drivers

You can use the Boot Camp drivers which integrates HFS read/write into Explorer.

- http://support.apple.com/kb/DL830

You don't need Boot Camp to download/install the drivers.

### [HFSExplorer](http://catacombae.org.preview.binero.se/hfsx.html)

Alternatively, you can use HFSExplorer:

> HFSExplorer is an application that can read Mac-formatted hard disks and disk images.
>   It can read the file systems HFS (Mac OS Standard), HFS+ (Mac OS Extended) and HFSX (Mac OS Extended with case sensitive file names).
>
> [image]

Comment: I have an acer laptop and I want to write to a ox journaled external hard drive. I would I do it?

Answer (score 1):

If you are connecting to the Mac over the network, you need to make sure SMB sharing is turned on.

1. First in System Preferences open Sharing

   [image]
2. Then check File Sharing and match folders that you want shared and with whom

   [image]
3. I allow both SMB and AFP.  The SMB handles the translation for Windows.

   [image]

These are the exact settings I use and I work and move files over Windows, OS X, and Linux.